# Using UnSafe code to make a pointer move to the next element for a custom class

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

Is it possible to do something like the following in C#?

```
unsafe string GetName()
{
    Foo[] foo = new Foo[2]; // Create an array of Foo and add two Foo elements
    foo[0] = new Foo { Name = "Bob" };
    foo[1] = new Foo { Name = "Jane" };

    Foo *ptr = &foo;    // Get address of the first element in the array
    ptr++;  // Move to the next element in the array

    return *ptr.Name;  // Expect Name to be "Jane"
}
```

I'm playing around with custom data structures, and I would like to be able to do this.

I know you can do it with int types etc, but what about user defined structs and classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this, but only if `Foo` is a struct where all the fields are "unmanaged types".  `int` is an unmanaged type; `string` is not. You should use the `fixed` statement to fix the array in place so that the garbage collector does not move it. Consult chapter 18 of the specification, and note that **when you turn the safety system off, it is off**.  That means that **you are responsible for understanding everything about memory management in C# when you write unsafe code**.  Do you understand everything about memory management?  If the answer is "no" then do what I do: **don't write unsafe code**.  I've been writing C# code for ten years and haven't had to write unsafe code (aside from compiler test cases) yet.

You simply should not do this in the first place. There's no *need* to use unsafe code. If you want something that acts like a pointer to the middle of an array you can do that in a typesafe manner without using pointers.

Here, I've even written the code for you:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/10/references-and-pointers-part-two.aspx

Comment: Hey thanks for your concise answer! I certainty don't pretend to know more then the high level memory model for C#, I'm basically just doing this for fun. The code above would never be used for production, I'm just attempting to make a generic thread-safe structure that's even faster then a singled threaded hashtable for example. More importantly I'm teaching myself some low level techniques that I fear I'm currently lacking. I will read parts one and two of your blog entry, cheers.

Comment: @user1515024: That's a good learning exercise. This would also be an opportunity to study the C# memory model, which is a lot weaker than the x86 memory model. You'll also probably find that generics and pointers do not mix well in C#.

Comment: I've been playing around with your ArrayPtr<T> code, it's pretty cool, I like it. But I have one question, why is it a struct instead of a class? If I want to use this on a large array, will that cause problem (or is the source array on the heap)? I see you made the struct in a functional pattern, I assume this is for thread safety? In your ArrayPtr, whats the pros of a struct over a class? I have never once used a struct (or seen one) in production code, perhaps I'm ill-informed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1515024: You have five questions, not one. First: I made it a struct because it is a **value type** because it is (1) very small, and (2) **logically a value**.

Comment: @user1515024: Second: all arrays are on the heap in C#. Arrays are *reference* types, not *value types* because they are (1) large, and (2) do not behave like *values*.

Comment: @user1515024: Third: No, I care not a whit about thread safety. You should always make value types immutable because mutable value types are a worst practice in C#. Think about it like this: when you add 1 to 2, you don't **mutate 2 into 3**. 2 stays the same. The result of the addition is a *new thing*.  If 2 could magically change into 3, that would be confusing. Values should always be treated as *values*, not *variables*.  Treat *variables* as variables.

Comment: @user1515024: Fourth: This is a frequently asked question on this site. Look it up.

Comment: @user1515024: Fifth: Many C# developers are very ill-informed about the semantics of value types. I have written extensively on this subject. This would be a good place to start: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/value+types/ -- start from the bottom, those are in reverse chronological order.

Comment: Thanks for answering all of those, five for the price of one!